# Position of first significant digit after the decimal point

Tags: java, decimal

How can I calculate the position of the first significant digit in a fraction?

Here are a few example inputs with desired output

```
0.123456    // 1st sign. number position = 1
0.0012345   // ...                       = 3
0.000012345 // ...                       = 5
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need for looping. You can simply use the following formula:

```
Math.ceil(-Math.log10(d))
```

**Example:**

```
public static int firstSignificant(double d) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(-Math.log10(d));
}

// Usage
System.out.println(firstSignificant(0.123456));    // 1
System.out.println(firstSignificant(0.0012345));   // 3
System.out.println(firstSignificant(0.000012345)); // 5
```

A note on some corner cases:

- 0 has no first significant digit. For this case the formula evaluates to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
- You haven't specified what should happen with negative values, but if you want them to behave like positive values you can use `Math.abs(d)` instead of `d` in the formula.

Answer (score 4):

You could loop over it count the number of times you need to multiply by ten before it becomes greater or equal to one:

```
public static int significantDigitNum (double d) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (d < 1) {
        d *= 10;
        ++cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

EDIT:
As David Conrad commented, this function will only work for positive numbers. To also support negatives:

```
public static int significantDigitNum (double d) {
    int cnt = 0;
    d = Math.abs(d);
    while (d < 1) {
        d *= 10;
        ++cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: You should take the absolute value first, otherwise it will loop forever.

Comment: I think, but I haven't checked, that it also fails for NaN.

Comment: @DavidConrad it return 0 for NaN, but nice catch on the negative numbers (edited, thanks!). Should probably also treat for zeroes, but doubles and equality... yuck.

Comment: It's probably undefined for zero. (Where's the first significant digit in `0.0000000...`? :-) The best you can do is probably to return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which happens to be what the formula I propose evaluate to.

Answer (score 0):

You can check each character if it is a number between 1-9.

```
    String numberString = "0.000012345";
    int position = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<numberString.length();i++){           
        if(String.valueOf(numberString.charAt(i)).matches("[1-9]")){
            position=i-1;
            break;
        }
    }
```